# How to print searchCriteriaBuilder query in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, search-criteria

How to print searchCriteriaBuilder query in magento 2 ?
I tried below code but it is not working.

```
$childProductIds = [1,2,3];
    $sortOrder = $this->sortOrderBuilder->setField('price')->setDirection('ASC')->create();

    $this->searchCriteriaBuilder->setSortOrders([$sortOrder]);
    $this->searchCriteriaBuilder->addFilter('entity_id', $childProductIds, 'in');
    
    $searchCriteria = $this->searchCriteriaBuilder->create();
    $searchCriteria->setPageSize(1)->setCurrentPage(1);
    $productList = $this->productRepository->getList($searchCriteria);
print_r($productList->getSelect()->assemble());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside of the `ProductRepositoryInterface` inside of the `getList` method, you'd do `$collection->getSelectSql(true)` at some point after the collection is actually loaded.

When Magento builds a product collection, it layers the filters in one at a time so the full query is not assembled until time of collection load.

You might want to do the following to force the collection to load and then print the query: `$collection->getItems(); echo $collection->getSelectSql(true);`

Also, you have `$productList->getSelect()->assemble()`. However, SearchResultsInterface does not have a getSelect method.